# Ayuda con los props en React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, props

Tengo un flatlist con categorías, que lleno con datos de un API, quiero pasar los datos de un elemento del flatlist a otra ventana detalle, tengo duda de cómo hacerlo utilizando react navigation, anexo mi código

Mi componente de categoria

```
import React, {useState, setState} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, ImageBackground, Text, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';


const Category = (props) => {
  navigation = useNavigation();


  return(
  <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('Details')} style={styles.wrapper}>
    <Text  style={styles.title}>{props.name}</Text>
    <Text> {props._id} </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  title: {
        color:'#59709F',
        fontSize: 40,
        fontWeight:'bold',
        textShadowColor: 'rgba(255,255,255, .75)',
        textShadowOffset: {
            width: 2,
            height: 2
        },
        textShadowRadius: 0,
  },
  wrapper:{
    width: 250,
    height:100,
    borderRadius: 10,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    margin:10
},
});

export default Category;
```

Quiero pasar los props del elemento de la lista que seleccioné a un nuevo componente categoría, estoy algo perdido

Answer (score 0):

Lo podrías hacer pasando un segundo parámetro que son las `props` que quieres pasar.

Por ejemplo:

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('Details', props)}>
   <Text>Hola</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Fíjate en que al navigate le estas pasando un parámetro más que son las props.

Te recomiendo que mires la [documentación](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#navigate) oficial ya que esta todo documentado.

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Lo he intentado de esa forma, pero de esa manera pasaría los props de todos los elementos de mi lista, yo sólo quiero pasar los datos del elemento que seleccioné

Comment: Entonces pasa solo el dato/s seleccionado/s. Ej: `navigation.navigate('Details', this.state.selectedItems)` o algo por el estilo.